# Released Products Screen opening with no data AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have imported Product,Released Products using DIXF. I have two legal entities like US, AUS. After importing i opened Products, Released Products screens from US legal entity. They are opened perfectly fine.

When I move to AUS legal Entity and opened Products screen. It looks good. I opened(by right click open) Released products screen, it opened with empty data in the form with "No Record " as Title.

Thats my problem. When I right click and view details, its showing form with data. But its not showing data on form when I right click and open or double click to open. But when my colleague logged in to him vm and opened the client and tried opening this released product, he can be able to see the details on form.

Looks like its only happening to me. This is not happening for released Products which already existed. This is happening only for the ones which I imported through DIXF.

I tried resetting user data, restarted client and tried with new records but no luck.

Can someone help me how can I fix this/ or how to approach this to solve these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The released products form contains an inner join of several tables. 
If any of the inner joined records are missing, the item will not show up in the form.

You may verify that this is the case by using the table browser. If the item shows up in InventTable but not in the form, something is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But When I click on View Details instead of double click open, form opens with data. It means all joins are fine right? What difference does it make between view details and double click open?

Comment: Sure, not a data problem. The form is called with slightly different parameters depending on how it is called. Try debugging.

Comment: Can you verify whether you and your colleague have same security roles assigned to that company?

Comment: Yes we have same roles.I tried in another colleagues login and he is having an issue just like me. I don't understand why does it works in US legal entity and not in Aus legal entity?  @pradeepMV

Comment: Yes, I did. There is a customized datasource added(innerJoin) to the form for which Vendor data needs to be added which is given an incorrect value in data which caused issue and stopped populating data. I changed it to correct value and its working fine. @Jan